# Error using EF6 DbFunctions.TruncateTime comparing DateTime

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, datetime

I`m trying to retrieve some data from a data range using the following code:

```
    var rotas = db.X.Where(r => r.DataDaExecucao != null)
    .Where(r => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(r.Date.Value) >=         System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(startDateTime))
    .Where(r => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(r.Date.Value) < System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(endDateTime))
    .Join(db.T, r => r.Id, t => t.X_Id.Value,
    (r, t) => new
    {
    id = r.Id,
    start = r.Date.Value.ToString("s"),
    end = r.Date.Value.AddDays(1).ToString("s"),
    title = t.Z.Name,
    allday = false
    }).ToList();
```

"Date" properties are Nullable< DateTime>.

I`m getting the following error message:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
>
> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Also, I don`t have the System.Data.Entity.dll assembly referenced in my csproj.

Ideas?

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Related to System.Data.Entity, what EF version do you have and what .net framework version you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the anonymous type using [SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where it will also generate the sql query.

In your case you use `ToString("s")`, meaning you want to get the date part of second that can be replaced by `SqlFunctions::DatePart`. And `Date::AddDays` can be replaced by `SqlFunctions::DateAdd`.

```
new
{
    id = r.Id,
    start = SqlFunctions.DatePart("s", r.Date),
    end = SqlFunctions.DatePart("s", SqlFunctions.DateAdd("d", 1, r.Date)),
    title = t.Z.Name,
    allday = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

DateTime.ToString() cannot be converted into a SQL statement by LINQ to Entities. e.g.

> start = r.Date.Value.ToString("s")

The thing to do is call .ToList() to force the LINQ to Entities to execute its underlying SQL query. That way the remainder of the LINQ statement will use LINQ to Objects (in-memory query of a collection of objects).

In your case I would break the LINQ statement into 2 parts:

1. The first half which queries the DB with LINQ to Entities SQL generation, and calls .ToList() at the end
2. The second half which runs LINQ to Objects to do the in-memory part.

Comment: The .ToList() forces a complete retrieval of any rows selected. This may be ok where only a small result set is expected but is otherwise a good way to really grind things to a halt.