# get items from db between two dates: Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Trying to get items from db but getting System.NotSupportedException, found how to avoid but to me it doesn't help. Any ideas to how I can avoid this exception?

```
return await DbContext.Members.Where(
     x => x.ClientId == criteria.ClientId 
         && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.CreatedOn).Value.Date 
                  >= criteria.StartDate.Value.Date 
         && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.CreatedOn).Value.Date 
                  <= criteria.EndDate.Value.Date
    ).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Try it without the `.Value.Date`

Comment: What's the full error message - does it match this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794561/error-using-ef6-dbfunctions-truncatetime-comparing-datetime

Comment: @stuartd wow, well, that is solution for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DbFunctions.TruncateTime` truncates the time from the date, so there is no need to use `.Value.Date`, which is what is causing the exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **EntityFunctions.TruncateTime** :

```
return await DbContext.Members.Where(
                        x => x.ClientId == criteria.ClientId &&
                        EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.CreatedOn) >= criteria.StartDate.Value.Date &&
                        EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.CreatedOn) <= criteria.EndDate.Value.Date
                        ).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: What difference is there between `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` and `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911301/what-are-the-difference-between-entityfunctions-truncatetime-and-dbfunctions-tru

Comment: _"There is no difference."_